# Are methods included in a Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

What I mean by this question is if I have a thread that runs some code and that code uses a method that isnt in a thread, is that method also ran in the same thread. Here is a code example of what I am talking about. This is an example using android but Im guessing the same applies for java.

```
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Logic

                        randomMethod();
                    }
                }).start();
```

Then a random method:

```
    public void randomMethod()
{
    //This method is not wrapped in a thread.
}
```

So is the randomMethod() ran with the thread that it was called on or is it a separate thread?

Comment: It runs in the thread it was called on.

Comment: Ok my experimenting hinted at this but thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods run in the context of the caller. You can always check your thread id(s) with [`Thread#currentThread()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread%28%29), for example

```
// How to get the current thread id and name
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
System.out.printf("Thread: %d - %s%n", t.getId(), t.getName());
```

**NOTE**: A regular Java application is started on the `main` thread (with id "1").

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is called [Anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) in Java. In this way Thread instance has access to all methods (even private) inside parent class, so you can call your `randomMethod()`, but this method will be called within anonymous class context - in your case - in a separate thread

So short answer to your question - yes, method will be run in a separate thread

Answer (score 0):

The word "thread" has two meanings in Java:  A thread (little t) is a path of execution through your code.  Thread (big T) is a Java standard library class with methods that can be used to create and manage little-t threads.

Methods belong to classes.  The methods that belong to the Thread class (not counting its private methods) are exactly those methods that are described in the javadoc for that class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Little-t threads *call* methods, but they do not *own* them.  Any (little-t) thread in your program can, in principle, call any method in your program.  Whether or not it actually does depends entirely on you.